# Wrapping multiple queries with multiple outputs

Tags: c#, sql, generics, refactoring, dapper

I have this class, in which I am wrapping dapper calls in order to do something like

```
var results = SqlWrapper.ExecuteQuery<Product,Customer>("SELECT id FROM Products; SELECT id FROM Customers;");
```

Where

```
results[0] = List<Product>
results[1] = List<Customer>
```

I support 1,2,3 output objects, but would like arbitrary. The class is also ugly and full of copy and pasted code. I account for if I want to reuse a connection by optionally passing a connection but the code just seems unclean. What I would really like is a way to define `params T[]` but as I understand that doesnt work. Is this any way this code can be cleaned/shortened?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using Dapper;

namespace SqlWrapper
{
    public static class SqlWrapper
    {
        private const string SqlConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=TTDS;User Id=sa;Password=sa;";


        public static List<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string sql, object param = null, SqlConnection sqlConnection = null)
        {
            if (sqlConnection != null)
            {
                return sqlConnection.Query<T>(sql, param).ToList();
            }

            using (var tempSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
            {
                tempSqlConnection.Open();
                return tempSqlConnection.Query<T>(sql, param).ToList();
            }
        }


        public static List<dynamic> ExecuteQuery<T1, T2>(string sql, object param = null, SqlConnection sqlConnection = null)
        {
            if (sqlConnection != null)
            {
                return MultiQuery<T1, T2>(sqlConnection, sql, param);
            }

            using (var tempSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
            {
                return MultiQuery<T1, T2>(tempSqlConnection, sql, param);
            }
        }

        public static List<dynamic> ExecuteQuery<T1, T2, T3>(string sql, object param = null,
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = null)
        {
            if (sqlConnection != null)
            {
                return MultiQuery<T1, T2, T3>(sqlConnection, sql, param);
            }

            using (var tempSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
            {
                return MultiQuery<T1, T2, T3>(tempSqlConnection, sql, param);
            }
        }

        private static List<dynamic> MultiQuery<T1, T2>(SqlConnection sqlConnection, string sql, object param = null)
        {
            var rv = new List<dynamic>();

            using (var grid = sqlConnection.QueryMultiple(sql, param))
            {
                rv.Add(grid.Read<T1>().ToList());
                rv.Add(grid.Read<T2>().ToList());
            }

            return rv;
        }

        private static List<dynamic> MultiQuery<T1, T2, T3>(SqlConnection sqlConnection, string sql, object param = null)
        {
            var rv = new List<dynamic>();

            using (var grid = sqlConnection.QueryMultiple(sql, param))
            {
                rv.Add(grid.Read<T1>().ToList());
                rv.Add(grid.Read<T2>().ToList());
                rv.Add(grid.Read<T3>().ToList());
            }

            return rv;
        }


        public static void ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection sqlConnection, string sql, object param, int? timeout = null)
        {
            if (sqlConnection != null)
            {
                sqlConnection.Execute(sql, param, commandTimeout: timeout);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var tempSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
                {
                    tempSqlConnection.Open();
                    tempSqlConnection.Execute(sql, param, commandTimeout: timeout);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like maybe you are overthinking it a bit.  Dapper already has a QueryMultiple method that you can use to handle multiple queries and the `grid.Read<T>` to allow you to read the results.

Comment: Yes, I am wrapping `QueryMultiple` into a more abstracted class. There are additional things to the class not seen here but the main point of these methods is to abtract away the whole grid and reading and seamless support 1-3 resultsets with one overloaded function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some untested code that demonstrates a couple of ideas that I had.

1. While "using" is pretty awesome, you can pare down your code some if you optionally create the connection first and then, if necessary, dispose the sqlConnection in a finally block.
2. If you return a `Tuple<List<T>,List<U>,List<V>>` you can have strongly typed return values that you can easily use
3. If you call your most complex function from those that are less complex, you can minimize your duplicated code.

---

```
public static class SqlWrapper
{
    private const string SqlConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=TTDS;User Id=sa;Password=sa;";

    private class NoResult { }

    public static List<T1> ExecuteQuery<T1>(string sql, object param = null, SqlConnection sqlConnection = null)
    {
        return ExecuteQuery<T1, NoResult, NoResult>(sql, param, sqlConnection).Item1;
    }

    public static Tuple<List<T1>, List<T2>> ExecuteQuery<T1, T2>(string sql, object param = null, SqlConnection sqlConnection = null)
    {
        var result = ExecuteQuery<T1, T2, NoResult>(sql, param, sqlConnection);
        return Tuple.Create(result.Item1, result.Item2);
    }

    public static Tuple<List<T1>, List<T2>, List<T3>> ExecuteQuery<T1, T2, T3>(string sql, object param = null, SqlConnection sqlConnection = null)
    {
        List<T1> list1;
        List<T2> list2 = null;
        List<T3> list3 = null;
        bool needsDisposed = false;

        if (sqlConnection == null)
        {
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            needsDisposed = true;
        }

        try
        {
            using (var grid = sqlConnection.QueryMultiple(sql, param))
            {
                list1 = grid.Read<T1>().ToList();
                if (typeof(T2) != typeof(NoResult))
                {
                    list2 = grid.Read<T2>().ToList();
                }
                if (typeof(T3) != typeof(NoResult))
                {
                    list3 = grid.Read<T3>().ToList();
                }

                return Tuple.Create(list1, list2, list3);
            }
        }
        finally { if (needsDisposed) sqlConnection.Dispose(); }
    }


    public static void ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection sqlConnection, string sql, object param, int? timeout = null)
    {
        bool needsDisposed = false;

        if (sqlConnection == null)
        {
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            needsDisposed = true;
        }

        try { sqlConnection.Execute(sql, param, commandTimeout: timeout); }
        finally { if (needsDisposed) sqlConnection.Dispose(); }
    }
}
```